# Which Provider Can Provide High Transaction Fee Cap?

Tags: web3-providers

Geth's default transaction fee cap is 1ETH/BNB/HT controlled by [txfeecap](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options). Infura and quicknode use the default option and will raise error `tx fee (1.2 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)` for high fee transaction. Is there any provider that can provide high transaction fee cap? Cost of hosting full node is too expensive so don't consider it here.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment of writing, [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) has txfeecap set to 100 on EVM-based nodes such as Ethereum, Polygon, Binance Smart Chain and Fantom by default: https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/4419341748633

Answer (score 0):

You can run [your own GoEthereum node](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/) and configure it to accept any transaction fee. Though I am not sure if the peer-to-peer network will reject txs with too high fees.

Comment: Running own nodes is too expensive,  if someone wants multiple chains, he needs to run several nodes.

Comment: It is less expensive than Infura subscription https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513